# ng-repeat with in-line edit, how to make the first (or last element) have editmode = true?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, inline, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an ng-repeat which loops over some items, and am using an editmode parameter to switch between a label and inputfield to let the user edit the value in-line.

Now I would like the functionality to be like this:
when the user presses the Add button, a new empty (or default) item is created, that has the editmode set to true (so that the input textbox shows with the save button, rather than the label with the edit button).

I have googled a lot about this but could not find a clear answer so far. :(

Code is as follows:

```
      <div ng-repeat="todo in todos">
            <span data-ng-hide="editMode">
                {{ todo.name }}
            </span>
            <input type="text" placeholder="{{ todo.name }}" data-ng-show="editMode" data-ng-model="name" data-ng-required />

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-ng-hide="editMode" ng-click="editMode = true">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
            </button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-ng-show="editMode" ng-click="editMode = false; editTodo(todo._id)">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" ng-click="deleteTodo(todo._id)">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use editMode as scope variable. Use it as todo's object field (todo.editMode). Set it to true for new todo object.

Answer (score 2):

You could keep it simple by adding a separate input element outside of your ng-repeat.

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/YDkzgtOSNpqDehnPkpZe?p=preview

Add another div element below your ng-repeat as below:

```
<div>
    <button ng-show="!addNew" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" ng-click="addNew=true">Add New</button>
    <br>
    <div ng-show="addNew">
       <input type="text" ng-model="newTodo.name" ng-required />
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" ng-click="addNewTodo()">
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
       </button>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" ng-click="resetNewTodo()">
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I do not like to repeat the whole HTML block a second time though but this would definitely work. Cheers.

Comment: You are right. It is not a good idea to add so much verbosity. I would go with ngRepeat's $index/$first/$last cursors to implement it better, as suggested by @developer10.

Answer (score 1):

The `ngRepeat` offers you `$index` - current position, `$first`, `$last` - so you can check against those to determine when you're on the first or when you reached the last element.

Comment: Thanks, this has prompted me to read up on the ng-repeat and how it works in more detail.